# Jenkins Surefire Report Show Failure

Tags: maven, jenkins, reporting, surefire

I am running tests via Jenkins and Maven using `surefire-report:report` goal. Even when some tests fail, Jenkins displays the Job as successful due to correct completion of the job. The Surefire Reports are correct corresponding to the test results. Are there any ideas how to configure Jenkins to run and report the tests properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is maven project or freestyle project? Why are you not using `mvn test`?

Comment: Yes it is a maven project. Maven `test` would be fine if I would be able to run e.g. `surefire-report:report-only` also after `test` fails and indicate a build failure in Jenkins.

Comment: report-only - `Creates a nicely formatted Surefire Test Report in html format. This goal does not run the tests, it only builds the reports. `. Jenkins need XML report by default.